# use Effect is repeating lottie animation

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, lottie

Learning React here, and I'm simply trying to display a lottie animation.  Seems fairly straight-forward, but I'm having some trouble with the useEffect hook.  I'm using the hook to render the animation on page load, but it keeps repeating itself (sometimes twice or more).  I know this is because useEffect will fire more than once, but I'm not sure how to handle this.  I just want one animation on the page.  How can I achieve this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./index.scss";
import lottie from "lottie-web";

const Hero = () => {
  const lottieContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: lottieContainer.current,
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      animationData: require("../../assets/Lottie/developer.json"),
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="hero">
      <div ref={lottieContainer}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Maybe you could make a quick reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-section-szzl1p?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of [React strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), it tries to help you to detect unwanted side effects and runs all `useEffect` hooks twice, so you could see that you forgot something. And in that case you forgot to add cleanup function, without it `lottie` creates 2 animations without cleaning up the first one. Just add this to your code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('lottie'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      animationData: require('../../../assets/Lottie/developer.json')
    });

    // Return clean up function here
    return () => instance.destroy();
  }, []);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-72031767-clii06?file=/src/components/Home/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` method as you have write it will execute the inside function when your component is mounted, your `useEffect` is ok, your lottie config object has a `loop` property that repeat your animation. You should replace by

```
lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: lottieContainer.current,
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: false, //or delete this line
      autoplay: true,
      animationData: require("../../assets/Lottie/developer.json"),
});
```

Comment: This is likely it, the useEffect is fine.

Comment: I thought that too initially, but it keeps happening - even if I remove the loop property.

Comment: Also, the loop property only loops the animation.  Which is what I want.  I don't think that would cause it to duplicate itself.

Answer (score 0):

> import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"; import
> "./index.scss"; import lottie from "lottie-web";
>
> const Hero = () => {   const lottieContainer = useRef(null);
>
> useEffect(() => {
> constinstance = lottie.loadAnimation({
> container: lottieContainer.current,
> renderer: "svg",
> loop: true,
> autoplay: true,
> animationData: require("../../assets/Lottie/developer.json"),
> }); return () => instance.destroy();   }, []);
>
> return (
>
>
>    ); };
>
> export default Hero;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).